# Spring boot application Properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm receiving this error in Spring Boot -Application properties
I created Spring Boot starter project-Maven and opened application properties it shows Failed to create parts control
please help how to solve this error

```
> org.eclipse.tm4e.core.TMException: Unknown location for grammar
> <source.java-properties>  at
> org.eclipse.tm4e.core.registry.Registry._loadGrammar(Registry.java:133)
>   at
> org.eclipse.tm4e.core.registry.Registry.loadGrammar(Registry.java:86)
>   at
> org.eclipse.tm4e.registry.internal.AbstractGrammarRegistryManager.getGrammar(AbstractGrammarRegistryManager.java:149)
>   at
> org.eclipse.tm4e.registry.internal.AbstractGrammarRegistryManager.getGrammarForScope(AbstractGrammarRegistryManager.java:97)
>   at
> org.eclipse.tm4e.registry.internal.AbstractGrammarRegistryManager.getGrammarFor(AbstractGrammarRegistryManager.java:86)
>   at
> org.eclipse.tm4e.ui.text.TMPresentationReconciler$InternalListener.findGrammar(TMPresentationReconciler.java:406)
>   at
> org.eclipse.tm4e.ui.text.TMPresentationReconciler$InternalListener.findGrammar(TMPresentationReconciler.java:278)
>   at
> org.eclipse.tm4e.ui.text.TMPresentationReconciler$InternalListener.inputDocumentChanged(TMPresentationReconciler.java:226)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.fireInputDocumentChanged(TextViewer.java:2746)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.setDocument(TextViewer.java:2787)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.setDocument(SourceViewer.java:663)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionViewer.setDocument(ProjectionViewer.java:368)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.setDocument(SourceViewer.java:613)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.initializeSourceViewer(AbstractTextEditor.java:3990)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractTextEditor.java:3460)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.createPartControl(StatusTextEditor.java:64)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:452)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.genericeditor.ExtensionBasedTextEditor.createPartControl(ExtensionBasedTextEditor.java:83)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:154)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:101)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:362)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:139)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:411)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:333)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1015)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:781)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:752)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:107)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
>   at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:146)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4580)  at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:219)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
>   at
> org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:132)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
>   at
> org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:170)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:188)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:652)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:616)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:791)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:404)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1240)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3209)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$9(WorkbenchPage.java:3114)
>   at
> org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3083)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3074)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:570)  at
> org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:525)   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:363)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:170)
>   at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:287)   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:252)    at
> org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:252)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:382)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:554)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:796)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)  at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)     at
> org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:176)    at
> org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:793)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1108)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:270)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:310)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)     at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)    at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:635)   at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)  at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
```

Comment: Please provide more detail like some sample code, what you have tried etc

Comment: Can you share what you have added in maven dependencies

Comment: I have added open csv depedency,apache POI,POI-XML,jackson databind and commans-io-maven in pom.xml

Comment: I had added web,JPA,MYSQL DEVTOOLS,Thymeleaf while creating Spring boot starter project

Comment: please help to solve this Error

Answer (score -1):

Import the project into Spring Tool Suite (STS). It will resolve the issue.